# Create full height mobile menu in Genesis Child Theme Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am currently creating a website for my sisters' band and trying to figure out how to create a full width and height mobile menu in Wordpress (so PHP). The child theme is Genesis. Is there someone who can help me with this? Website if you want to check it out: http://wrongbandofficial.com

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure that you need to create menu from scratch I assume that you can use plugins it will save you a lot of time check this out :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/animated-fullscreen-menu/

If you need to create a full screen menu with css and js. You can give position:absolute; attribute to your .genesis-responsive-menu class once menu is opened and you can set it back to it is initial state once it is closed and right now menus width is set to auto which it will create it is width based on the content width of child so you will need to set that one to width:100%. Ofcourse it is not a fully solution but I think it should help you out with extra work.

As an extra for any kind of file changes on your theme please consider creating a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a static website? Since all your content is managed by Spotify and Instagram (this means that you don't need Wordpress). But anyhow you need to use CSS @media query. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
It automatically activates CSS rules based on the screen size. There you can create a menu for the mobile & tablet menu

Comment: My sister wanted it to be a Wordpress page.. But I solved it with plugin as ocliptus suggested :) thanks for your suggestion!